# (iPhone,Obj-C) Where does this "view" property come from?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, properties

I ran across this segment of code (in .m implementation file in an IBAction instance method):

```
UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] ...];
...
[actionSheet showInView:self.view];
```

self refers to the button but I wanted to know where I could find out about this "view" property since I looked up UIButton, UIView, NSObject, but could not find out where this "view" property came from.

(also, any corrections on terminology would be appreciated since I am trying to learn all the correct terms - I'm a beginner iPhone programmer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The view property is one of a UIViewController. The controller usually creates a view in its initialization, and is responsible for managing it. Any subclass of UIViewController will inherit this property. See [this link](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for more details. Also, you may want to familiarize yourself with MVC(model view controller), as this might make it more clear why the controller has a view property. See [this link](http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MVC.html) for more details.

Comment: In your UIViewController subclass, simply add the method:
- (void)viewDidLoad
Inside of it, you can put whatever you want to happen when your view finishes loading into memory.